# Is there something wrong with this foreach code?

Tags: php, programming-languages

```
foreach ($data['tests'] as $testname => $tests) {
echo "<h1>Extraction $testname Tests</h1>\n";
$function = $testfunctions[$testname];

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "<li>" . $test['description'] . ' ... ';
    $extracted = $extractor->$function($test['text']);
    if ($test['expected'] == $extracted) {
        echo " <span style='color: green'>passed.</span></li>";
    } else {
        echo " <span style='color: red'>failed.</span>";
        echo "<pre>Original: " . htmlspecialchars($test['text']) . "\nExpected: " . print_r($test['expected'], true) . "\nActual  : " . print_r($extracted, true) . "</pre>";
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\runtests.php on
>   line 49

p.s. the beginning of the code is line 49, so the probelm starts with the foreach statment.

Comment: Seems that either `$tests` or `$data['tests']` is not an array. Do a `print_r($data['tests'])` to see what it is.

Comment: it deosnt show nothing, but the erro still remian :((, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever i see that, it tends to mean that the thing i'm trying to iterate through isn't an array.

Check `$data['tests']` (and each inner `$tests`) to make sure it's not null/unset/empty, and that it's something iterable like an array.  Also keep in mind that older versions of PHP (before 5.0?) don't do iterable objects very well.

Comment: i fixed the error, the array wasnt poplauted with data, its was just a bit of syntax on line 40!! :))) thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the elements in `$data["tests"]` is probably not an array.

Add this before the foreach:

```
if (is_array($tests))
 foreach ($tests as $test) {...
```